# pthread_mutex_trylock? pthreads in Windows

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

/*//*/*/*/*/*/*/*//*/*/*/////*/*//*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*//*/*

```
pthread_mutex_t stop = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int a = 1;

void* decrement(void* arg)
{ 
    pthread_mutex_trylock(&stop);
    if(a > 0) { a--; } 
    cout << "Esecuzione thread tid" << endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&stop);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t tid;

    pthread_attr_t tattr;
    pthread_attr_init(&tattr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&tattr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

    pthread_create(&tid, &tattr, decrement, NULL);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&stop);
    if(a > 0) { a--; } 
    cout << "Esecuzione thread main" << endl;

    cout << a << endl;

    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Why the thread detached to the main's thread continues its execution instead of returning to the caller with EBUSY?

Comment: You're not checking any error codes anywhere, so how can you tell if they're being returned or not?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing specific to Windows in your problem.  You actually misunderstood how `pthread_mutex_trylock()` works.

- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html

> The `pthread_mutex_trylock()` function shall be equivalent to `pthread_mutex_lock()`, except that if the mutex object referenced by mutex is currently locked (by any thread, including the current thread), the call shall return immediately.
>   ...
>   The `pthread_mutex_trylock()` function shall fail if:
>   `[EBUSY]`
>   The mutex could not be acquired because it was already locked.

It is not the `decrement` thread but `pthread_mutex_trylock()` which returns (may return) `EBUSY` (you didn't check...)

By the way it is also possible for the `decrement` thread to finith its execution earlier than `pthread_mutex_lock(&stop)` in the `main()` thread.  It's totally undeterministic.